# Swift Webview UIButton Interaction

Tags: html, swift

Is it possible to interact with a website, when the website is loaded in the web view? So that on the web view is a UIButton and then a button in the website is triggered if you trigger the UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

You can run JavaScript code using WKWebView's stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method. JavaScript can do all sorts of stuff.

If you know a button's ID, this line of JavaScript will click on the button:

```
document.getElementById("*insert button ID*").click()
```

Here's some Swift code that you can then use to "click" the button.

```
let jsResult = webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptByString("document.getElementById(\"*insert button ID*\").click()
```